# Filtering the output from the ping command

Tags: grep, scripting, ping, filter

I have a fairly simple little script. Basically, it performs ping over a given domain. It is like this:

```
ping -c2 $1 | head -n4
```

And it prints out for example:

```
PING google.com (172.217.17.206): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.17.206: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=2.474 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.17.206: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=2.668 ms
```

which is okay for me.

But for example like you know sometimes the ping command does not return any response from the ICMP request. Like for example:

```
ping intel.com
PING intel.com (13.91.95.74): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
--- intel.com ping statistics ---
```

And when this happens the script stuck for several seconds and then it resumes on its way.
I'm trying to think of a way when this happens to just skip it and just proceed down. I actually not sure if it is possible at all.
I was thinking at first to pipe it to grep for 'Request timeout' or to put the result in a variable and then cat | grep the variable.

Can someone think of a way for this and is it possible at all to just skip the execution when it hits Request timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want it to be stuck for "several seconds" when a server fails to respond, add a timeout using the `-W` option.  For example:

```
ping -c2 -W2 "$1"
```

`-W2` sets a two-second time.  Change the limit to fit your needs.

#### Aside

When referencing shell variables, like `$1`, always put them in double-quotes, like `"$1"`, unless you explicitly know about and want *word splitting* and *pathname expansion*.

#### Documentation

From `man ping`:

> -W timeout
>    Time to wait for a response, in seconds. The option affects only timeout in absence of any responses, otherwise ping waits
>   for two RTTs.

Comment: Thank you. This should work for me.

Answer (score 1):

@John1024's answer is spot-on for Linux distributions.  Since your question is not operating system-specific, I'll include a BSD solution.

BSD's `ping` command (also Mac OS X) has more granularity in some of its timing parameters.  Most network connections have round-trip times well under one second.  Indeed, many connections have an RTT of less than one millisecond.  [FreeBSD's man page for `ping`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ping) specifies that the `-W` option accepts an argument in units of milliseconds:

> -W    waittime
>
> Time in milliseconds to wait for a    reply for each packet sent.
>   If    a reply arrives later, the packet is not printed as replied,
>   but considered as replied when calculating    statistics.

The equivalent command using FreeBSD's `ping` then is:

```
ping -c2 -W2000 "$1"
```

The higher resolution of FreeBSD's `-W` parameter permits one to supply a `-W` value closer to the actual RTT that is expected.

Suppose a host `testhost` is known to be nominally 75 milliseconds away, round-trip.  A `-W` value of 80 will yield:

```
jimsdesk : 14:45:58 /root# ping -W80 -c2 testhost
PING testhost (10.111.33.21): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.111.33.21: icmp_seq=0 ttl=240 time=74.385 ms
64 bytes from 10.111.33.21: icmp_seq=1 ttl=240 time=74.478 ms

--- testhost ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 74.385/74.431/74.478/0.046 ms
```

A smaller `-W` value of 50 produces:

```
# ping -W50 -c2 testhost
PING testhost (10.111.33.21): 56 data bytes

--- testhost ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss, 2 packets out of wait time
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 74.466/74.538/74.611/0.073 ms
```

Suppose another host `testhost2` is much closer, typically less than 4 milliseconds away.  We'll specify a tighter -W tolerance of 4 milliseconds.  Let's also increase `-c` to sample a larger number of packet trip times:

```
# ping -c10 -W4 testhost2
PING testhost2 (10.216.177.146): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.216.177.146: icmp_seq=0 ttl=59 time=3.730 ms
64 bytes from 10.216.177.146: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=3.899 ms
64 bytes from 10.216.177.146: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=3.949 ms
64 bytes from 10.216.177.146: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=3.668 ms
64 bytes from 10.216.177.146: icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=3.881 ms
64 bytes from 10.216.177.146: icmp_seq=5 ttl=59 time=3.725 ms
64 bytes from 10.216.177.146: icmp_seq=6 ttl=59 time=3.826 ms
64 bytes from 10.216.177.146: icmp_seq=8 ttl=59 time=3.726 ms
64 bytes from 10.216.177.146: icmp_seq=9 ttl=59 time=3.728 ms

--- testhost2 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss, 1 packets out of wait time
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 3.668/3.867/4.539/0.241 ms
```

The output above shows that nine of the ten packets made the round trip in 4 milliseconds or less, but one (seq 7) did not.

Ratcheting down even further, a lot of LAN RTTs are just under a millisecond, but not always.  Running `ping -c100 -W1 10.10.1.1` on a local network yielded:

```
...
--- 10.10.1.1 ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 100 packets received, 0.0% packet loss, 10 packets out of wait time
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.664/1.081/18.547/1.898 ms
```

90 out of 100 packets returned in less than a millisecond, but the other 10 did not.

The localhost interface is a sub-millisecond round-trip on most computers.  Unfortunately, FreeBSD's `ping` does not accept decimal values for `-W`:

```
# ping -c3 -W1 localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.020 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.020 ms

--- localhost ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.018/0.019/0.020/0.001 ms

# ping -c3 -W.999 localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes

--- localhost ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss, 3 packets out of wait time
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.020/0.022/0.025/0.002 ms
```

It would appear that a `-W` value of `.999` is parsed as `0`.

Comment: I don't have access to a BSD box so thanks for including the BSD info.